# How can DuckDuckGo list my question as a search result only after 7 minutes I have submitted it on this site?

Tags: discussion

I assumed "indexing" without any special treatment would take longer.

Is there any story behind this, or are they just being extra useful? :)

Comment: Web crawlers such as Googlebot and DuckDuckBot crawl sites once in every few seconds to update indexing and things they know about/on your site. The search results depends on the keywords as well. I don't think this question has to do anything with SE or AU, in general.

Comment: I thought I was allowed to "discuss" it :)

Comment: I never said it *shouldn't* be discussed :). It's just how those search engines work.

Comment: @Levente this was one question I had before, and totally forgot to ask or even search for it; and here you are asking it! thank you;  really! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google and DDG search engine bots crawl StackExchange sites regularly (usually every few seconds or 30 seconds or whatever they're set for), because we're high activity sites.

This is just how these search indexer crawlers work, it's not an SE/AU specific thing it's just how those crawlers are written.

Comment: Yeah, my amazement comes from the part how fast it happens. It exceeded my assumptions / expectations, that's all. Thank you.